# Implementing IF with the XMLStarlet Edit function

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I'am fighting with the another XMLStarlet challange. What I am trying now is to update one field value with the value of another one. In my case from time to time a source field `INVOICE/INVOICE_ITEM_LIST/INVOICE_ITEM/PRODUCT_FEATURES/FEATURE/FVALUE` not exist and XmlStarlet crashed. Is there the way to avoid it and copying only if the source field is available?

Thanks in advance for your help

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "INVOICE/INVOICE_ITEM_LIST/INVOICE_ITEM/QUANTITY" -x    "../PRODUCT_FEATURES/FEATURE/FVALUE/text()"
```

My example XML:

```
<INVOICE_ITEM_LIST>

<INVOICE_ITEM>
      <PRODUCT_FEATURES/>
      <QUANTITY>to_be_set</QUANTITY>   
</INVOICE_ITEM>

 <INVOICE_ITEM>
          <PRODUCT_FEATURES>
               <FEATURE>
                      <FNAME>TotalQuantity</FNAME>
                      <FVALUE>32.500</FVALUE>
                      <FUNIT>MTR</FUNIT>
               </FEATURE>
        </PRODUCT_FEATURES>
        <QUANTITY>to_be_set</QUANTITY>
 </INVOICE_ITEM>
</INVOICE_ITEM_LIST>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an xpath predicate to select only those nodes that have an FVALUE:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/INVOICE_ITEM_LIST/INVOICE_ITEM[PRODUCT_FEATURES/FEATURE/FVALUE]/QUANTITY" \
  -x "../PRODUCT_FEATURES/FEATURE/FVALUE/text()"
```

Note that I have changed the path to fit your example XML.